# Limiting the number of characters in a user Scanner input in String in Java

Tags: java, string, input, string-length

This code is supposed to print the user's name when they enter it and limit it's length to 20 characters, but it only works when the user's name is longer than 20 chars. I get en error when it's below 20. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you.

```
String name;

Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your Name ");
name = textIn.nextLine();

String cutName = name.substring(0, 20);
if (name.length()>20) {
    name = cutName;
System.out.print("Hello " +name+"!");
}
```

Comment: You have to do the lengthcheck before you do the substring. You could just use: `String cutName = name.length() <= 20 ? name : name.substring(0,20);`

Comment: set System.out.print("Hello " +name+"!"); out of loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place your String cutName inside the if, the error should disappear. You cannot take a substring from a string that is longer than the String itself.

```
if (name.length()>20) {
    String cutName = name.substring(0, 20);
    name = cutName;
}

System.out.print("Hello " +name+"!");
```

Comment: No problems the answer from Berger should also work, but this seemed a bit simpler for a beginner.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both and they did work, but, like you said, yours was simpler for a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Just take the lower index between 20 and the `String` 's length .

```
name.substring(0, Math.min(20,name.length()));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter your Name ");
name = textIn.nextLine();

if(name.length()>20)
    name = name.substring(0,20);
```