# Read only 3 digits in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. In C I would use: `scanf("%3i")` to read in only 3 digits even if the user inputs 20 digits at the terminal.

I did not find how to do this with `scanner.nextInt()`;

Comment: You can't do that Using Scanner, the best you can do is truncate the input.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @JorgeCampos You can truncate the input. Similar solution is provided here https://stackoverflow.com/q/36937124/10553411

Answer (score 1):

You might want to test, if the input is a number. If this is the case, you can scan a string and cut it to three chars and parse it to an int.

```java
    // Declaration
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String string = "";

    // Scanner
    System.out.println("Enter a number with 3 digits: ");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) scan.next();
    string = scan.next();

    // Cut the string if it is longer than 3 digits
    if (string.length() > 3) string = string.substring(0, 3);
    // Parse string to int
    int threeDigitInt = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution without dancing with trampoline is:

```
final int input = Integer.parseInt(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine().substring(0, 3));
```

Comment: I have to disagree with this solution. The real answer is you can't using Scanner. Your answer is simply stating how to TRUNCATE the input not limiting it as C does. Please add this detail to your answer.

Comment: The only one detail is in fact that's working solution without dancing with trampoline))